# "Every Sunday" or "on every Sunday"?

Tags: prepositions

I replied to my friend's question like this:

> It's something I do every Sunday.

But now that I think about it I think there should've been "on" before every. But still I'm not sure because the version without "on" sounds more natural to my ears.

Comment: Campared with the usage of "every day", I tend to think the version without 'on' is correct. But I'm not exactly sure. I'm not a native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something I do every Sunday.

It's something I do on every Sunday.

We normally don't use the preposition on" before time expressions beginning with each, every, next, last, this, etc. So the use of the "on" in the second sentence is unnecessary.

Besides, if you say you do something on Sunday(s), Monday(s), etc. , it also conveys the sense that you do it on every Sunday, Monday, etc. So you can also say: It's something I do on Sunday or Sundays instead of It's something I do every Sunday that is more clear and emphatic.

In AmE, you can also use Sundays,Mondays, etc. as an adverb to mean every Sunday, every Monday, etc. as follows, but it's not much common:

It's something l do Sundays.

He works Sundays (every Sunday).  (Merriam Webster).

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Dan, I too believe that *on* is more specific.

> He's coming ***on Sunday***

On the other hand, if you generalize it, the *on* is omitted

> I visit the place every Sunday

---

Note that *every Sunday* is **stronger** than just *Sundays.*

> I *do something* on Sundays

...talks about doing something on Sundays frequently. Nevertheless, *every Sunday* shows more rigorous and strict routine.